# How to show loading image for UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiimageview, xcode5

I have a code to show image from remote URL.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = nil;

        imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]];

        if (imageData){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // UIKit, which includes UIImage warns about not being thread safe
                // So we switch to main thread to instantiate image
                UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                self.imageLabel.image  = image1;


            });
        }
    });
```

But it takes 2 seconds to download the image. I tried to put animated loading image to the UIImageView, but not worked. How can I implement a loading image for that 2 second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there is no built in method in iOS to provide a placeholder image. You can accomplish this task using a framework called `SDWebImage.framework`. In one of my projects I had to display placeholder images while the main images are loading from the server. I used the same framework and displayed images using `UICollectionView`, the code I used is:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionCell *Cell = [collectionView
                            dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                            forIndexPath:indexPath];



   [Cell.imageview setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];

    return myCell; 
}
```